# Promise fulfillment handler undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Very basic, it seems, implementation of a Promise based implementation is not returning the value/data I expect to see.

This is how I am expecting this interface to work:

```
sdk.request(options) => Promise~Response → Object (JSON)
```

Here is the code in my model:

```
return sdk.request(options).then(function (value) {
    return value;
});
```

When I log the return of the model, I see this:

```
{
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _progressHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined,
    _settledValue: undefined
}
```

When I see `_fulfillmentHandler0: undefined` that seems to imply that there is no fulfillment handler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

But the fulfillment handler does seem to be present:

```
return sdk.request(options).then(function (value) {
    // fulfillment handler, right?
    return value;
});
```

Comment: is this maybe because the `handler` is an anonymous function? did you tried to pass a normal named function as handler?

Comment: You want to log the `value` inside the **handler**, not the promise returned by `then`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The `then` handler will create a new promise object** and that will be returned so that the promises can be chained.

Quoting [bluebird's documentation on `then`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#thenfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise),

> Returns a new promise chained from this promise.

---

In your case,

```
sdk.request(options)
```

returns a promise object and that has a fulfillment handler, which is the following `then` handler.

```
.then(function (value) {
    return value;
});
```

but the `then` handler returns a new promise object, which doesn't have a fulfillment handler yet. That is why `_fulfillmentHandler0` is `undefined`.

You can confirm this like this

```
var promise = require("bluebird").resolve();
console.log(promise);
```

will print

```
{ _bitField: 268435456,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _settledValue: undefined }
```

since `promise` has no fulfillment handler yet. But when you attach a handler to it, like this

```
var promise1 = promise.then(function () {})
console.log(promise);
```

will print

```
{ _bitField: 268435457,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function],
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: 
   { _bitField: 0,
     _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
     _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
     _progressHandler0: undefined,
     _promise0: undefined,
     _receiver0: undefined,
     _settledValue: undefined },
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _settledValue: undefined }
```

**Note 1:** A single promise object can have more than one fulfillment handlers. That is why the output above shows `[Function]`, which means an array of functions.

**Note 2:** You don't have to worry much about the properties of the Promise objects. These are implementation details.

---

As per the [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738667/promise-fulfillment-handler-undefined/30738773?noredirect=1#comment49535628_30738773),

> I want to log/verify the data/value returned by the `sdk.request`

Yes, you can very well do that with bluebird. You can simply [`tap`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/tap.html) the promise and you can print the actual resolved value, like this

```
return sdk.request(options).tap(console.log);
```

will print the actual resolved value and you can attach a `then` handler to process the resolved value.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Let me take a few minutes to work out a couple things, then I'll mark this answer if I everything works.

Comment: @jerome If you want to log/verify the actual resolved value, you can use `tap` function, like I have shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Still working through this. I actually have promises a couple of levels deep, but your initial answer got me on the right track, so marking it.

Comment: is it possible to manipulate with the tap and try to filter some attributes in the resulting object . Rather than doing it on the .then function because I am having a generic handler for .then function

Comment: @IsmailIqbal You can, but please don't. Add another `then` handler.