# node js fulfillmentHandler0 undefined with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, bluebird

I have a function that does the following:

```
function getUrl(id) {
    let params;
    return attModel.getById(id)
      .then(resData => {
        const attachmentMetaData = resData.shift();
        params = {
           Bucket: 'some-bucket',
           Key: [
             attachmentMetaData.fieldA,
             attachmentMetaData.fieldB,
             attachmentMetaData.fieldC
           ]
        };
        return isEnabled(attachmentMetaData.fieldD);
  })
  .then(isEnabled => {
    if (isEnabled) params.Key[1] = '0';
    params.Key = `${params.Key.join('/')}.png`;
    return params;
  })
  .then(params => { return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params); });
}
```

When I call this function from the controller, and console.log the result, I get the following:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _trace: 'some traces ...'
}
```

I've tried attaching a .then as suggested by [Promise fulfillment handler undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738667/promise-fulfillment-handler-undefined), but still get the same result.

Comment: You should not care about the internal representation of the promise - everything that begins with an underscore. Hint: the final result promise always has no handlers.

Comment: You don't want to log the promise, you want to chain `.then(console.log, console.error)`

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to set the result of getUrl(1) to a variable and use it. But when I console.log to check the result, I am expecting a URL in string, but I get a Promise instead. I tried chaining a .then(url => { return url; }); but that also didn't work. @Bergi

Comment: You cannot assign a future result to a variable right now. Store the promise, and when you need the result wait for it by adding a callback and using the value inside there.

Comment: @uckc `.then()` always returns a promise. It will never return anything else. You need to take Bergi's advice.